# Why is Windows slow when disk usage is high?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, performance

I have always noticed that whenever disk usage is high (above 50%) the entire computer slows down, mainly explorer.

My question is, what is the reason behind this? Why is that when disk usage is high, performance is at its lowest? Does it have something to do with the HDD or is it an OS or CPU thing?

For example, I have some Node projects that aren't really needed anymore so I'm using `rimraf` to delete the `node_modules` directory, which contains thousands of files and directories. During the execution I notice that the disk usage is at about 50% and I honestly can't do anything during that time. I can't browse any other directory or right click a folder.

I have Windows 10 21H1 x64 which is installed in a separate drive (an SSD) from the files I'm deleting. I've also tried searching for an answer to this but most of the results are about fixing issues that cause 100% disk usage.

Comment: The reason Windows is "slow" when there is high disk usage is due to the priority of that I/O.  To put it simply accessing a file has a higher priority than the mouse button click or moving an application's window to a different location.  That is the reason, often in cases of high I/O errors, you will often see those actions "catch up" after Windows gives up on the I/O attempts. If you are unable to do "anything" when you are deleting a file that indicates a larger problem.  For decade you were able to do multiple things while files are being deleted.

Comment: @Ramhound This makes a lot of sense. As for doing "anything" I meant in the explorer since I can still use other applications like Chrome and such, but they are much slower than they should be.

Answer (score 2):

A hard drive can only read one track (or several sequential tracks) at one time. If the head has to move to get the next logical track, it will take time.

5400-rpm drives are common in economy machines and are very slow compared to even 7200-rpm drives and certainly compared to SSD drives.

A way to speed up hard drive access if you can do it is (a) see if you can delete or back off many small files that slow down access and (b) set defragmentation to be automatic and run (say) weekly.

If you can convert to SSD, that will do a lot to alleviate your issue.

Comment: While this explains why it's usually slow for an HDD to do time-consuming operations like deleting thousands of files, it doesn't explain the main question as to why the entire computer slows down.

Comment: If you are moving / deleting many small files on a slow disk, it can take a while. Otherwise, normal operations on s slow disk (updates, databases) can take time as well. A fragmented hard drive slows down the whole machine.

Answer (score 1):

The slow speed is due to an implementation choice by Microsoft, a bad programming choice by the developer or a bad configuration choice by the user. File delete should not have high priority.

[Microsoft actually suggest the developer to rename the file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/closing-and-deleting-files#:%7E:text=To%20reuse%20a%20file%20name%20immediately%2C%20rename%20the%20existing%20file.) (at programming time) to get a faster delete (in the sense of permitting reuse of a filename).

It could also be done at runtime to make a delete script or program that renames synchronously and then deletes the renamed files slower and asynchronously.

rimraf has a lot of options. Did you try anything like [rimraf.moveRemove(path, [opts])](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf#rimrafmoveremovepath-opts:%7E:text=rimraf.moveRemove(path%2C%20%5Bopts%5D))?

You could also try to call the delete in a separate process from node and set a [lower priority](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#ossetprioritypid-priority) on that process.